# 32 Amp to 30 amp

Tags: electrical

We removed our old cook top and purchased a new one. The new top is 32Amp and the old is 30. The electrician told us he could not legally  connect it because if we ran all the burners at once it could melt the wires. The gauge of the wires are the same. Do they make a reducer or can we connect it anyway?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack exchange!  Where in the world are you?  This is important to know, since your local building codes will determine what solutions are legal in this situation.

Comment: Do you know what size wire you have out of your junction box? Your breaker size in the main panel?

Comment: Breakers protect wires so they don't melt.  If you used more electricity than you should, the breaker trips and you have to reset it.  Sounds like the "electrician" was either confused or dumbing down an explanation for you but we need more details to tell you anything else.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What size breaker supplies that circuit, and is it only for the cook top? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: This sounds like over the pond (32 amp) I would believe the electrician, if the OP did fire everything it’s the insulation that would possibly melt and then the wires could short. Kinda like asking an electrician to wire a 30 amp device to a 20 amp circuit here.

Comment: Where are you on this planet? What size is the breaker in your breaker panel/distribution board, and what size are the wires feeding the cooktop?

Answer (score -1):

If the electric installation is limited to 30A, a 32A device **must not be used**. Being gross negligence or even wilful intent in court,
 an insurance may also refuse to compensate for any **possible damage**.

But instead of replacing the installation to match a 32A (or higher) load, which may imply to swap cables, breakers and plugs, there is a much less expensive solution if the new cook top is of a non-induction type. 
An **induction cook top** (or one or two separate stand alone units)  does need less power (saving money and energy), is faster heating the content (saving time), burn-ins are less likely (e.g. milk) and it is also much safer.
It should be possible to fine tune the temperature, some devices do have **20 degree Celsius steps** which are too coarse.

Comment: No matter what the type if the circuit is 30 a and the new one requires 32 amp any  licensed sparky would not install it . Why because they could get fined and lose their license.

Comment: @EdBeal Exactly that is why I wrote in the first sentence "If the electric installation is limited to 30A, a 32A device must not be used." Of course the induction cooking unit(s) are supposed to require not more then 30A, otherwise they must not be connected to the 30A-installation.

Comment: The only reason I did not upvote was because you went into types of loads and not your code. On this side of the pond we have the national electric code that defines different size wires , for example a 15 amp breaker needs 14 awg wire, 20 amp 12 awg wire and 30 amps requires 10 awg wire, our code book ~1200 pages or the version I have. Many are un informed  and even electricians that only work in 1 small area may not know about all the others. On top of that there are exceptions and then local state rules so it can be quite convoluted here. Give us help on your code for a +

Comment: I am not thrilled with this answer because we know far too little at this point to say much of anything.  For instance 30A circuits probably use the exact same wiring as 32A circuits, in which case they change a breaker and are G2G.   It may be 30/32 *un-derated*, e.g. It might derate to 37.5/40, meaning same 40A wire and breaker.    Also, it's a bit too alarmist, especially given that so much info is still missing.

Comment: My intention was to inform all interested readers about the dangers in that kind of situations, since a replacement of an electric device is very common - independent on more information given or not given by the author of the question (we see it quite often that the author does not react anymore on request for more information after some time).
In this case it is also likely that the author does not know how the wires are installed behind the walls. As mentioned, many factors are important to calculate the maximum load like neighboring/adjacent wires, use of trays/pipes, ...

Comment: ...embedding in thermal insulation, even aluminium wires are common in some countries etc. 
So implicitely the code is taken into account in general by the statement that it is safe to limit the maximum current of the replacement device/appliance to the limit of the given installation resp. to the same value as the old device/appliance.
But in this case of a cook top to be replaced the safety could be improved - again in general - by choosing an induction cooking system. 
...

Comment: ...The statistics of insurance companies (in Europe) tells us that most fires in private homes (ca. 30%) start in kitchens - caused by cooking or other high power electric devices. 
Induction cookers are automatically switched off if the pan/pot is removed or if a time limit is exceeded. Furthermore the temperature of the device is much lower.

Comment: It would be compliant to install here in NZ, as the 30A MCB would limit maximum demand to the safe rating of the cable...